# Question closed as duplicate, but the linked question was deleted

Tags: discussion, feature-request, exact-duplicates, deleted-questions

This is related to [Question closed as a duplicate, link points to question closed as a duplicate](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32789/349785), but it is more problematic.

The question (Q) [Prove that quotient topology $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ is the circle topology.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4137390) was closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4136863) (Q') which (together with its answer) was deleted later for the reason that it needs details or clarity.

In my opinion this must not happen. If question (Q') is deleted and does not point to another question which is still open, the original question (Q) which was closed as a duplicate of (Q') should be reopened.

Does this make sense? If yes, would it worth to do this automatically by a new software feature?

Comment: FYI, the network Meta post [Don't allow Community to delete dup-master questions, and warn voters against the same](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226504) indicates the Roomba script doesn't first check for a question being a target of a duplicate post before it deletes a question. However, [How was this user able to delete their own question that was a duplicate target of another question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353323) shows that, ...

Comment: (cont.) apart from the deprecated mobile apps (but which [Mobile app infrastructure being decommissioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026) states will soon no longer be supported at all), users aren't allowed to delete duplicate target posts.

Comment: Looking at the posts [tagged exact-duplicates+deleted-questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exact-duplicates+deleted-questions) I see (among others) these past discussions: [What to do with duplicates of deleted questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32004), [This question is an exact duplicate of: Page Not Found](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23450) and [Duplicate of a deleted question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15236). (The third one is shown among the related questions ATM, too.)

Comment: One of the older questions [contains this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/209965/duplicates-of-deleted-questions#resultSets). It returns 170 results now. (The questions posted in June 2020 says that there were 109 results at the time.)